How to Keep Headers and Image Glued Together During Window Resizing in PyQt6
I'm working on a GUI where I have a QMainWindow with a layout containing three widgets stacked vertically: a top header, an image, and a bottom header. The top and bottom headers are custom QWidgets with a blue background, and the image is displayed using a QLabel with a QPixmap. The Image is just a generic 400x400 image.
Here's my code:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap, QColor, QPalette
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QSize

class ColorWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        # Top Header
        top_header = ColorWidget('blue')
        top_header_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        top_header_layout.addWidget(QLabel(parent=top_header, text='Image name'))
        top_header.setLayout(top_header_layout)
        layout.addWidget(top_header)

        # Image
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('Images/Path')
        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.image_label.setMinimumSize(QSize(100, 100))
        self.image_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.image_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        layout.addWidget(self.image_label)

        # Bottom Header
        bottom_header = ColorWidget('blue')
        bottom_header_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        bottom_header_layout.addWidget(QLabel(parent=bottom_header, text='Caption'))
        bottom_header.setLayout(bottom_header_layout)
        layout.addWidget(bottom_header)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.adjust_image_size()

    def adjust_image_size(self):
        container_size = self.image_label.parentWidget().size()
        pixmap_width = self.pixmap.width()
        pixmap_height = self.pixmap.height()

        max_width = container_size.width()
        max_height = container_size.height()

        new_width = min(max_width, pixmap_width)
        new_height = min(max_height, pixmap_height)

        if new_width / pixmap_width > new_height / pixmap_height:
            new_width = new_height * pixmap_width / pixmap_height
        else:
            new_height = new_width * pixmap_height / pixmap_width

        self.image_label.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(int(new_width), int(new_height), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

There are three issues that I'm having:
If I expand the window vertically, the top and bottom frames get separated from the image label.
If I expand the window horizontally, the top and bottom frames expand quicker than the image resizes.
If I resize the window to its smallest size possible, the image looks a bit rectangular.
To fix the first issue, I've added Spacer Items to the layout to sandwich everything in, which works for the most part, except when I make the window narrow and tall.
To address the second issue, I tried setting a max width of 400 pixels (the width of the photo). This sort of works except if I make the window smaller, the top and bottom frames still stretch further than the image width.
How can I improve this code so that the top and bottom frames are always "glued" to the image and resize as a whole? I want the widgets to resize as if they are one single widget.



After implementing some possible solutions, the widgets are resizing more in unison but still not as if they were the same widget. Below are the edits:
# Add this in Main Window Init method
self.setMaximumWidth(400)
self.setMaximumHeight(400)

# Add this statement before the Top Header
layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding))

# Add it again after the bottom header
layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding))

EDIT:
To clarify, this is what I want the widgets to do when I resize the window. For these examples, I photoshopped the top header and bottom header into the original picture. This is only an image




Edit 2
Subclassing a Qwidget that manages its layout and its geometry:
class AspectRatioWidget(ColorWidget):
    def __init__(self, widget, color='#18181d'):
        super().__init__(color)
        self.widget = widget
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        self.aspect_ratio = None

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        if self.widget.pixmap():
            pixmap = self.widget.pixmap()
            self.aspect_ratio = pixmap.width() / pixmap.height()
            if self.aspect_ratio:
                container_width = self.width()
                container_height = self.height()

                new_width = container_width
                new_height = int(container_width / self.aspect_ratio)

                if new_height > container_height:
                    new_height = container_height
                    new_width = int(container_height * self.aspect_ratio)

                self.widget.resize(new_width, new_height)
                self.widget.updateGeometry()

updating the main code:
aspect_ratio_widget = AspectRatioWidget(self.image_label)
layout.addWidget(aspect_ratio_widget, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)


Your description shows some problems, but doesn't address how those widgets should be actually placed while resizing. What should happen if the height is larger than the widgets require? Should they be aligned on top/bottom or centered? Should some of them adjust their size in order to fill the remaining vertical space? How would the image be resized? Layout management is quite complex, and depends on each widgets size hints, restraints and policies. Please take your time to update your post and clarify what should happen with different size combinations, even with some mock up images.

Hi @musicamante, I will work on updating my post and clarify what I want. But basically what I want is that the frames always have the same width as the image. Never to expand further than the image width or get shorter than it. Basically, I want the top and bottom frames to be as if they have been photoshopped into picture and they resize and expand as if they were part the same image.

@musicamante updated my post to reflect what I'm trying to accomplish

So, you want a size-ratio-based widget, considering the sizes of the image and the labels. This isn't easy, especially considering that the labels have fixed minimum sizes caused by the font restraints. The only QWidget solution I can think of is to use a subclass: considering the complexity, you should probably opt for a custom widget that manages its layout and internal geometry on its own, including size hints. That's not impossible, but also not immediate. Are these interactive widgets? Should the font have a fixed size? Because you may consider using the graphics view framework instead.

I tried that approach of subclassing the QWidget. It worked well, except that if I reduce the window size, the widget gets smaller but it won't resize again if I expand the window. I have included the relevant code in the edited section. What would be a good first approach with using the graphics view framework?

Please add the custom widget related code as a single code block, so that we don't have to arbitrarily copy/paste things (risking to make the code not properly reproducible). The graphics view implementation is quite different, and is currently off topic based on this post. I suggest you to do proper research on the matter and try to implement it, then eventually edit this post to include that attempt or create a new one.

I was able to solve this using the graphics view framework as suggested by @musicamente
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap, QFont, QColor, QBrush
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 400)

        # Create QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene, central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        # Load and add the image
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('Images/GenericImages/ImagePlaceHolder')
        self.pixmap_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.pixmap)
        self.scene.addItem(self.pixmap_item)

        # Add top and bottom text labels with background color boxes
        self.top_rect = QGraphicsRectItem()
        self.top_rect.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('blue')))
        self.scene.addItem(self.top_rect)
        
        self.top_text_item = QGraphicsTextItem("Image Name")
        self.top_text_item.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        self.top_text_item.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        self.scene.addItem(self.top_text_item)

        self.bottom_rect = QGraphicsRectItem()
        self.bottom_rect.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('blue')))
        self.scene.addItem(self.bottom_rect)

        self.bottom_text_item = QGraphicsTextItem("Image Caption")
        self.bottom_text_item.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
        self.bottom_text_item.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.GlobalColor.white)
        self.scene.addItem(self.bottom_text_item)

        # Initial layout update
        self.update_layout()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.update_layout()

    def update_layout(self):
        # Get the size of the view
        view_size = self.view.size()

        # Calculate the scaling factor to fit the pixmap within the view while maintaining aspect ratio
        pixmap_width = self.pixmap.width()
        pixmap_height = self.pixmap.height()
        view_width = view_size.width()
        view_height = view_size.height() - 40  # Adjust for text items height

        scale_factor = min(view_width / pixmap_width, view_height / pixmap_height)
        new_width = int(pixmap_width * scale_factor)
        new_height = int(pixmap_height * scale_factor)

        # Update the pixmap item size
        self.pixmap_item.setPixmap(self.pixmap.scaled(new_width, new_height, Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation))

        # Center the pixmap item in the scene
        self.pixmap_item.setPos((view_width - new_width) / 2, 20)

        # Update the top text and background positions
        top_text_width = self.top_text_item.boundingRect().width()
        top_text_height = self.top_text_item.boundingRect().height()
        self.top_rect.setRect((view_width - new_width) / 2, 0, new_width, top_text_height + 10)
        self.top_text_item.setPos((view_width - top_text_width) / 2, 5)

        # Update the bottom text and background positions
        bottom_text_width = self.bottom_text_item.boundingRect().width()
        bottom_text_height = self.bottom_text_item.boundingRect().height()
        self.bottom_rect.setRect((view_width - new_width) / 2, new_height + 20, new_width, bottom_text_height + 10)
        self.bottom_text_item.setPos((view_width - bottom_text_width) / 2, new_height + 25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



This is a good start, but still not yet effective. Some issues: 1. you're considering the final geometries only based on the pixmap size, but, in reality, you should compute the overall height also considering the text height; 2. you're basing geometries on arbitrary values, specifically, using the point size of the font, which is almost never a real pixel size; 3. graphics items have parent/child relations similar to widgets, so the QGraphicsTextItems should actually be children of the QGraphicsRectItems; 4. the view may have borders and scroll bars, you cannot just rely on its size().
